# Python for-loop jumps over the second element of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The for loop is supposed to go through a list and add the elements to another list until it encounters an empty string. However, it keeps jumping over the second element.

The for-loop is supposed to go through a list("baa"), adding every element to a different list("foo"), until it encounters an empty string. At that point it is supposed to print out both of the lists. However for some reason the loop keeps jumping over the second element of my list, not adding it to "foo". I have no clues on any fixes or alternatives.

Code:

```
baa = ["1","2","","3","","4"]
foo=[]
for o in baa:
    baa.remove(o)
    if o =="":
        break
    else:       
        print(o)
print(baa)
print(foo)
```

Output:

['2', '3', '', '4']
['1']

Comment: Don't edit the list you are iterating over.

Comment: Right.  The iterator remembers the position in the list.  When you consume the first item, the pointer is set at the second item.  When you delete the first item, what used to be the second item becomes the first and is skipped.

Comment: Or working backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
baa = ["1","2","","3","","4"]
original_baa = baa.copy()
foo=[]
for o in original_baa:
    baa.remove(o)
    if o == "":
        break
    else:       
        foo.append(o)
print(baa)
print(foo)
```

This avoids removing an item from a list that you're looping over, by first taking a copy that's not modified.
This also assigns the values to `foo` as the loop progresses.

You can also do this using `index` and without looping / explicitly removing items:

```
baa = ["1","2","","3","","4"]
try:
    foo = baa[baa.index("")+1:]
    baa = baa[:baa.index("")]
except ValueError:
    foo = []
print(baa)
print(foo)
```

The `try...except` is for the case when `baa` does not contain any `""`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for o in baa:
    baa.remove(o)
```

You're adding/removing items in a list at the same time you're iterating over it.

This causes odd behavior exactly as you are seeing.

Don't do that.